# universal nonabelian divisible group

Tags: topological-groups, divisible-groups

For this post, a group $G$ shall be referred to as **generally divisible**, in case $\forall{x\in G:}~\forall{n\in\mathbb{N}^{\times}:}~\exists{y\in G:}~y^{n}=x$.

**Note.** Here is no commutativity requirement on the group imposed!

**Question.** Let $\mathcal{D}$ be the collection of generally divisible, seperable metrisable topological groups. Is there $G\in\mathcal{D}$, such that for all $H\in\mathcal{D}$, there exists an injective homomorphism $f:H\to G$, which is open when restricted to its image? ${}^{\ast}$

---

($\ast$) i. e. the map $f: H\to f(H)$ is open, or equivalently, the inverse $f^{-1}:f(H)\to H$ is continuous.

Comment: Why don't you begin by showing an example of a "generally divisible, separable topological (non-abelian) group"?

Comment: @DonAntonio: Any nonabelian compact Lie group would do.

Comment: @Martin: I think you have to rip the assumption that the universal object is separable and metrizable (just look at the abelian case). Then you have a chance. You need to establish an amalgamation property to find the universal divisible group.

Comment: @MoisheKohan the question is somewhat trivial without the separable-metrizable assumption on $G$. Indeed, since there exists a set $\mathcal{D}'$ which meets each isomorphism class of $\mathcal{D}$, just define $G$ as the direct product (or restricted direct product) of all groups in $\mathcal{D}$, with the product topology.

Comment: @MoisheKohan what do you have in mind in the abelian case? at least for abelian discrete (countable) groups, there is such $G$, namely the direct sum of countably many copies of $\mathbf{Q}\times (\mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z})$.